# 'no tests executed error' when using phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, testing

When I am trying to run phpunit or try to run better phpunit, I am receiving the error 'no tests executed'

I have tried writing different code into the terminal to get it to run:

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --testsuite Feature Tests,
./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter only_logged_in_users_can_see_the_posts,
phpunit --filter only_logged_in_users_can_see_the_posts.
```

I am looking to be able to get a result from any test when entering a command.

Comment: This is my code for PostsTest.php `<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Post;

class PostsTest extends TestCase
{
       /* @test */
        public function only_logged_in_users_can_see_the_posts(){
        $response = $this->get('/posts')
        ->assertRedirect('/login');
        }

} `

Comment: Try `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --testsuite 'Feature Tests'`